# What are the steps in general to cross compile any open source for the specific target

Tags: cross-compiling, embedded-linux

My job is generally to take an open source from Internet. Cross compile it with the MIPSEL toolchain and get the binary. I struggle a lot to cross compile the code. What are the steps in general to cross compile any source package. I use the platform Linux. Like for example, CC, ld and what else?
Every source code has a different structure, I am unable to make out the similarity between the packages. how can I cross compile it? Are there any systematic steps to get it done? Please advise.

Comment: What do you want to cross-compile?  MIPSEL only tells something about the CPU, are you targeting Linux or some other OS?

Comment: I was doing for Connection Manager. Architecture is MIPSEL, OS is Linux.

Answer (score 1):

I can only assume that you downloaded some random OSS tarball and are stuck now. I can only give you some pointers, because I haven't discovered a universal, one size fits all solution yet, you'll probably have to experiment a bit before finding the approach that suits your needs best.  And I've still haven't encountered a nontrivial cross compilation job that went from start to finish without some tweaking, fiddling and lots of patience.

1. The basic solution: you will need a toolchain for your platform, have a look [here](http://www.linux-mips.org/wiki/Toolchains) if there's something pre-built that satisfies your needs, or head over to [Dan Kegel's crosstool page](http://kegel.com/crosstool/) that will largely automate the creation of a toolchain for the platforms supported by it, and that toolchain will allow you to compile and link all programs that have no other dependencies than the standard libraries.
2. many open source packages come with autoconf configure scripts that are crosscompilation-aware, ie adding `--target=xxxx` will actually make them use the right cross compiler.  This will often work but it may involve downloading and crosscompiling/installing some libraries first. The major issue will be an autoconf script that tries to compile a small piece of code to study its output, to determine some feature of the environment.  Sometimes this can be solved by manually modifying configure, or by disabling some unneeded feature via eg `configure --without-xxxx`
3. If your target system is an embedded Linux system tools like [Buildroot](http://buildroot.uclibc.org/), [OpenEmbedded](http://openembedded.org/wiki/Main_Page) or [ELDK](http://www.denx.de/wiki/DULG/ELDK) will automate not only the creation of a usable toolchain, but also the cross compilation of many commonly used libraries and add on packages for Linux.  These tools also allow you to add other packages to their target lists (eg a custom application you created or bought), but that may involve manually solving some of the issues explained in 2) first.  But there the patch-scripts that come with these tools can be used to learn about commonly used tricks to get around compilation issues.

Comment: Thanks!, I have a MIPSEL-Linux toolchain. Recently, I tried cross building connection manager for the MIPSEL-Linux and found quite difficult. Also, I tried cross-compiling utility from ECLIPSE- TCF. All this lead to me a problem. There are so many utilities in X86 Linux, the same source when I need to compile for the embedded box, it is not easy. If you have any general guideline. Please share with the examples. Thank you ! very much.

Comment: That's what I tried to explain, there is as far as I know no one-size-fits-all solution.  Lots of searching on the internet will help, and there are several communities with forums filled with people working on crosscompilations. But there's a serious learning curve, I agree with that.